# Form 'jumpy' in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, forms, internet-explorer-7

I have 3 forms on a site I am developing  - http://79.125.12.14/contact/

They work fine on firefox et al, but they have this strange 'jumpy' effect in ie7. I'm a bit stumped.

The forms are embedded Javascript Wufoo forms.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more specifically what you mean by 'jumpy' effect?

Comment: Yes - when you click on an element in the form the background highlights. When you move out of the element with your mouse it 'jumps' (moves up a few pixels) - interestingly it doesn't do this when you tab through the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to Wuform embedding that surely listen for load events on IE before getting its maximum size.

```
var s7x3k7 = new WufooForm();
        s7x3k7.initialize({
        'userName':'cbtech', 
        'formHash':'s7x3k7', 
        'autoResize':true,
        'height':'514'});
        s7x3k7.display();
```

Maybe you should remove autoResize and put a fixed width in the options.

Comment: Hi SleepyCod, thanks for the response, unfortunatly this didn't work.